# Supervised Self-Organizing Maps: Overfitting or something else?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, supervised-learning, self-organizing-maps

I have built several classification/identification models to identify cat behaviour using accelerometer data. I am comparing two modelling techniques, Random Forest (RF) & Supervised Self-Organizing Maps (SOM), and two accelerometer mounting locations, collar & harness. Resulting in four different models:

1. Collar - Random Forest (CRF)
2. Harness - Random Forest (HRF)
3. Collar - SOM (CSOM)
4. Harness - SOM (HSOM)

**Information dataset**

- Size dataset: 40852 rows
- Train/test split: 70/30%
- SOM grid: 7x7
- Total of 32 identifier variables
- Total of 4 model building rounds (MR): **MR1** 15 behaviours; **MR2** 8 behaviours; **MR3** 6 behaviours; **MR4** 3 behaviours. (Total of 16 models)

**Results**
I calculated the Kappa & Overall accuracy for each model (See results below). As you can see, the values for the SOM models are higher than those of the RF models.

[image]

Because I still had 6 days' worth of accelerometer data, that was not used in any way to train or test the model, I decided to put this data into all the models and have it identify the behaviour. I then calculated the daily proportions for each behaviour and did a Dirichlet regression to compare the proportions for each behaviour between the models. To be able to test all the 16 models, I merged all the behaviours into one of three main categories: active, inactive or maintenance. As you can see below, despite the lower performance values of the RF, the RF models identify much more similar than the SOM models do. The proportions as identified by the RF models, are also more similar to those found in literature for cats.

[image]

**My question**

I am not a statistician and have some trouble trying to figure out why the SOM models have such high performance values, while identifying very variable between the SOM models. I would expect the SOM models to identify very similarly due to their high performance values. One of the possible explanations I can think of, is maybe an overfitting issue for the (supervised) SOM models? If anyone has any other ideas that I could look into, I will be very greatfull.